# ¿Como le asigno caracteres especiales a toda una columna?

Tags: excel

Necesito agregar los caracteres especiales a toda una columna de una tabla Excel como en el primer registro ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la última versión de Excel, si escribes a mano los 2 primeros casos, Excel detectará el patrón y te ofrecerá autorellenarlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero siempre puedes concatenarlo tú manualmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La fórmula utilizada simplemente es `=A1&"',"`